# Implementing Node as a generic class

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, nodes

I recently started learning Java and the last thing I was going over was generic programming and now linked list. Now, I'm trying to implement the node class from linked lists as generic, but I was having some trouble. I'm trying to declare a `toString` method that can iterate through this linked list and print its elements, however I keep getting a `NullPointerException` every time I call `link.toString()` and I'm confused on why I'm getting this error. I know that the format of my `toString` method is not as efficient as it can be but I was trying to follow my book instructions. I'm presenting my `Node` class and the applications one as well.

```
public class GenericNode<E> {

    private E data;
    private GenericNode<E> link;
    public GenericNode(E intialData, GenericNode<E> initialLink){
        data=intialData;
        link=initialLink;

    }
    public GenericNode<E> addNodeAfter( E element ) {
        link = new GenericNode<E>( element, link );
        return link;
    }

    public String toString(){


        String field1=" ";
        String field2=" ";
        String result=" ";

        if(data==null){
            field1="dummy";
            System.out.println("in dummy");
        }
        field1="Data: "+ data.toString()+ "\n";
        if(link==null){
            field2="null in tail!";
            System.out.println("in tail");
        }
        field2="link: data: "+link.data.toString() ;


        if(link!=null){
            result=field1+field2+link.toString();
        }

        return field1+field2;

    }
}
```

---

```
public class NodeAppilication {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        GenericNode<String> head=new GenericNode<String>("Paul", null);
        GenericNode<String> tail=new GenericNode<String>("Saul",head.addNodeAfter("Saul"));
        //figure 1
        System.out.print(head.toString());
        //figure2
        tail.toString();

        GenericNode<String> dummy=new GenericNode<String>(null,head);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your checks for `null` are missing an `else`:

```
if(data==null){
    field1="dummy";
    System.out.println("in dummy");
} else { // <<== Add an "else" here
    field1="Data: "+ data.toString()+ "\n";
}
if(link==null){
    field2="null in tail!";
    System.out.println("in tail");
} else { // <<== And here...
    field2="link: data: "+link.data.toString();
}
```

Currently, your code checks for `null`, sets the value of `field1` and `field2` to the default, and then immediately tries to dereference a `data` or a `link`, causing a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and I implemented this code and it worked and no longer get the NullPointerException, I just have one more question, according to the instructions for this problem I'm suppose to get this output: data: Paul
link: data: Saul
link: null in tail! However I do not get the last line where it shows that my tail does not point to anything, is that because of the way I implemented head and tail? Thank you again, I really do appreciate the help!

Comment: @user2012891 Your current code goes through two links, and ends at that. You need to add a loop to go through the links, so that you could print lists of arbitrary length.